# Change the credentials used by Microsoft Git Provider in visual studio 2013

Tags: git, visual-studio

I was using the Microsoft Git Provider in Visual Studio 2013 to clone projects from our git repository. I think the first time it asked me for some credentials, and ever since I could pull, commit and push my changes. **But**, recently I had to change my password for that repository (outside the visual studio), and no I always receive the 401 error saying that I'm not authorized. **The problem** is that I don't know how to change my credentials which are used by the visual studio.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was wondering where the visual studio stores these credentials used by the `Microsoft Git Provider` and finally found it.

The steps you have to do, assuming you are using Windows 10, is as follows:

1- Control Panel
2- User Accounts
3- Manage your credentials
4- Windows credentials
5- Under the **Generic Credentials** find the URL of the repository and click on it
6- Edit
7- Change the password to the correct one
8- Done!

Comment: What if I don't find the URL there?

Comment: It seems that (later versions of) Visual Studio will ask you for credentials after some failures. Just restart VS (to lose the cache) and try again.

Comment: For the first time I found a viable solution to do this: just remeber that usually GIT and DEVOPS want a TOKEN for a password. That should solve this